# Must every character in a campaign that uses the Honor ability score have one?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, campaign, optional-rules

In a campaign that uses the Honor ability score (*Ability Options, DMG p. 264–5), does everyone have to have an Honor score? If only one person has an Honor score, is it balanced so that the character is not more powerful (by having more ability points)?

What about NPCs?

Comment: Is your question basically "can only a few PCs and NPCs have honor (or sanity) scores or do I have to do it for everyone?" or is it something else?  Paragraph 1 is pretty clear on this option being for a campaign.  Your question needs more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, this won't break the game.

From your comment that clarified your question:

> I suppose my question hopes for a little more - does the game break if
>   only one person takes honor? e.g. if one character is a Ronin-type who
>   comes from another culture that is honor based and is now in an
>   environment where everyone else is not honor bound.

Even though the DMG p. 264-265 discussion is for a whole campaign (all or none), **no, it doesn't break the game** if only one player has that feature.  What it does is make your job as DM a little more challenging.  It also has consequences for the player whose Honor is in play.

Doing this thing with Honor puts your Ronin in the position of the older versions of D&D Paladin (even the 1e AD&D Cavalier).  For those classes, the code of honr significantly influenced some of the decisions made during play and added role playing requirements.

What penalties and boons you choose to apply in this case should balance out.  If it's too much benefit for the Ronin, the other players may feel you are playing favorites with that character.  If it's too much penalty the Ronin's player may get frustrated with the constraints.

You two need to do a little work ahead of time to come up with a balanced approach that will give this character what you are looking for: some benefit and some side effects.

Having a Paladin in D&D didn't break the game for four or five previous iterations.
You won't break the game by doing this.
What you will do is add a little work to your job as DM.  It may well be worth it.
Albert's answer about all others having a default Honor of 10 or 11 is a good idea if as you run into situations you didn't initially expect.

---

Note: I find Albert's opening point compelling, and agree with Albert that if this optional rule is used, it would fit better as a campaign wide attribute.  That said, your idea can be made to work.

Answer (score 6):

Everybody or nobody must use Honor.

This is how the Dungeon Master describes whether to use them or not.

> If you're running a campaign shaped by a strict code of honor or the constant risk of insanity, consider adding one or both these new ability scores: Honor and Sanity.

It's clear that it's a DM's election, not player's. That means it change rules of the game. You add, to the basic abilities, one or both of these, and everybody must adapt to it.

NPCs, following the same logic, should have them too, though feel free not to define them unless it should be relevant.

Since having Honor aplies to the campaign, not the player, in the case you'd decide to let one player has this attribute but not the rest, you are altering the balance. You either treat the rest of players as having 10 Honor or, whenever Honor would be used you find an alternative attribute.

Doing the first would be in fact like everyone having Honor. 
The second would make it balanced but somewhat weird, since the player with Honor sometimes would do better by not using it.

Anyhow, it wouldn't *break* the balance of the game, but could easily feel unfair for players.

Comment: This is an acceptable clarification of the DMG rules. I suppose my question hopes for a little more - does the game break if only one person takes honor? e.g. if one character is a Ronin-type who comes from another culture that is honor based and is now in an environment where everyone else is not honor bound.

Comment: Most of what you wrote was my initial feel.  Your approach is probably how I'd run it *if that optional rule was appealing to all of my players.*   (+1 from me).